# Netbeans 8.2 fail to start

Tags: java, linux, netbeans

**The problem:** I start Netbeans 8.2, the splash dialogue displays and it gets past Starting Modules and then quits.  The IDE doesn't start up. Something is still running after this (*ps aux | grep netbeans* shows the normal Netbeans process(es) running) I've looked in the log files (`~/netbeans-8.2/nb/var/log/` and ~/.netbeans/8.2/var/log/`) and found these warnings:

```
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: had to upgrade dependencies for module org.netbeans.asciidoc: added = [module org.netbeans.api.templates > 1.0, module org.netbeans.api.progress.compat8 > 1.40, module org.openide.util.ui > 9.3, module org.openide.filesystems.nb, module org.netbeans.api.progress.nb > 1.40, module org.openide.filesystems.compat8] removed = []; details: [#243100: Separate desktop-independent utilities, Separation of desktop and cleanup, Swing dependencies split away, Templates API has been separated into its own module.]
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: had to upgrade dependencies for module show.branch.in.statusbar: added = [module org.netbeans.api.templates > 1.0, module org.openide.util.ui > 9.3, module org.openide.filesystems.nb, module org.openide.filesystems.compat8] removed = []; details: [#243100: Separate desktop-independent utilities, Separation of desktop and cleanup, Templates API has been separated into its own module.]
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: had to upgrade dependencies for module eu.doppel_helix.netbeans.plist.PropertyListSupport: added = [module org.netbeans.api.templates > 1.0, module org.netbeans.modules.csl.types/1 > 1.0, module org.openide.util.ui > 9.3, module org.openide.filesystems.nb, module org.openide.filesystems.compat8, module org.netbeans.modules.editor.document > 1.0, module org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing > 9.0] removed = []; details: [#243100: Separate desktop-independent utilities, Separation of Parsing and Indexing APIs, Separation of desktop and cleanup, Splitting parts of csl.api off into csl.types, Templates API has been separated into its own module., The old editor settings and completion APIs have been deprecated, see http://wiki.netbeans.org/EditorSettingsUpgrade and update your module.]
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: had to upgrade dependencies for module nb.maven.project.setjdk: added = [module org.openide.filesystems.nb, module org.openide.filesystems.compat8, module org.openide.util.ui > 9.3] removed = []; details: [#243100: Separate desktop-independent utilities, Separation of desktop and cleanup]
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: had to upgrade dependencies for module de.markiew.netbeans.plugin.restart: added = [module org.openide.util.ui > 9.3] removed = []; details: [#243100: Separate desktop-independent utilities]
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: had to upgrade dependencies for module com.peter.mavenrunner: added = [module org.openide.filesystems.nb, module org.openide.filesystems.compat8] removed = []; details: [Separation of desktop and cleanup]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.netbinox]: Install area set to file:/home/o.o/netbeans-8.2/
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.form.nb] use org.jdesktop.layout which is deprecated: Use javax.swing.GroupLayout instead. (In form editor: select Form ... in Inspector; change Layout Generation Style to Standard Java 6 code.)
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.lib, org.netbeans.modules.web.core.syntax, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting which is deprecated.
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.ide.kit, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.structure which is deprecated.
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.java.hints, org.netbeans.modules.maven.hints, org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee, org.netbeans.modules.web.beans] use org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.legacy.spi which is deprecated: Use Java Hints SPI (org.netbeans.spi.java.hints) instead.
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in Services/MIMEResolver/ marked with the position attribute: [SNIP: very long list of xml files]
WARNING [null]: Last record repeated 2 more times.
INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: Turning on modules: [SNIP: list of modules]
... [More Info entries]...
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in Toolbars/ marked with the position attribute: [Git], but some are: [File, Clipboard, UndoRedo, Build, Debug, Memory, Standard.xml, Debugging.xml]
INFO [org.netbeans.libs.svnclientadapter]: Javahl client adapter is not available
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.SvnClientFactory]: JavaHL not available. Falling back on SvnKit.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.subversion]: Finished indexing svn cache with 0 entries. Elapsed time: 0 ms.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.SvnClientFactory]: svnClientAdapter running on svnkit
```

I have not explicitly run any Netbeans updates.  Netbeans will work for a few days and then hit this issue.

**The workaround:** Uncle Google says (most search results, e.g. [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbeans/+bug/1531373) and also including SO) says to delete the Netbeans user directory, i.e. `~/.netbeans/8.2/` (as well as the Netbeans cache directory)  This works but I have to reinstall my plug-ins and redo my short-cut keys.

**My system:**

- Ubuntu 16.04 (Linux version 4.4.0-53-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_GB (nb))
- Java: 1.8.0_101; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.101-b13
- Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_101-b13
- NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)

**The question:** Where should I look for what makes Netbeans not load?  I hate the work around and would like to find the culprit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find in the ~/.netbeans/8.2/ folder if you see .locked file.
This file is created by netbeans when an netbeans instance running or bad stopped.
Juste deleted it and run again.

Comment: Thank you, I've backed up the .netbeans folder from the last fail but can only see a `lock` file.  I'll try it when the issue comes up next time.

Comment: I had deleted the /.netbeans. Folder so how I can make to delete .locked file

Answer (score 0):

It work for me
right click on downloaded package
- run as administrator 
than you will see Already installed packages and unmark package 
mine was Java EE then just click install it will solve the problem.